# $MaxPrecision doesn't work

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I want to set MaxPrecision low, to like 2 decimals, but after I set it, it stays at 5 regardless.

I've tried using two commands:

```
Block[{$MaxPrecision = 2}, 1.555555 + 2]
```

and simply:

```
 $MaxPrecision = 2
```

and then enter some calculations.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Version

"12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Any expression in which a machine precision number appears will produce a machine precision result

```
Block[{$MaxPrecision = 2}, {val = 1.555555 + 2, val // InputForm, 
  Precision[val]}]
```

[image]

```
Block[{$MaxPrecision = 2}, {val = SetPrecision[1.555555, 2] + 2, 
  val // InputForm, Precision[val]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the correct code, it works perfectly. Is there any way to write it as an option for matrix decomposition operation, something like JacobDecomposition[mat] // Precision[2] ? I'm asking because I need to decompose a matrix that includes numbers with sign " ` " and I can't substitute them with floating type numbers like 0` with 0. because that symbol disappears in the "Find & replace" window. Or is 0` so small it can be deleted?

Comment: `mat // SetPrecision[#, 2] &`